# Concept of invariant measures on space of differential forms?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry

I am not from mathematics background but I have some rudimentary knowledge of differential manifolds, topological spaces etc. I was, therefore, wondering if one can define an invariant measure on the space of differential forms $\Omega^r_p(M)$ i.e. the space of all $r$-forms at $p \in M$ where $M$ is a differential manifold?

Comment: An object cannot be alone "invariant": it is invariant *under something*, like a group action. Under what would you want a measure on the space of differential forms to be invariant?

Comment: @Didier If I would have known I wouldn't be asking this question. I want to know if there are some properties associated with the space of differential forms that may be used to define an invariant measure.